# Perform word match in a String until another word is found in the String

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm using **preg_match_all** to perform all match in a String

```
$match_this = '/cola/';
$sentence = 'cola this cola is a nice cola';

if(preg_match_all($match_this, $sentence, $matches)){
  echo 'match found'.'<br>';
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

But I want this match performing operation to stop when I encounter the word **nice** and **$matches** array shouldn't store any more matched word after that.

How the code can be modified for this ?

> There can be multiple times 'cola' comes before 'nice'. This is just
>   an example sentence. Again 'cola' and 'nice' are just example words.
>   The words to match and where to stop are randomly picked from
>   database. This code is for a word game.

Comment: there can be multiple times 'cola' comes before 'nice'. This is just an example sentence. Again cola and nice are just example words. The words to match and to stop are randomly picked from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the offset of nice, then run the preg match on the substring before it.

```
$sentence = 'cola this cola is a nice cola';

$match_this = '/nice/';
if(preg_match($match_this, $sentence, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
    $niceOffset = $matches[0][1];
    $match_this = '/cola/';
    if(preg_match_all($match_this, substr($sentence, 0, $niceOffset), $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
      var_dump($matches2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$match_this = '\bcola\d\b';
$until = '\bnice\b';
$sentence = 'cola1 this cola2 is a nice cola3';

if(preg_match_all("/$match_this(?=.*$until)/", $sentence, $matches)){
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cola1
    [1] => cola2
)
```

I've added a number at the end of each `cola` to be sure it matches only the ones that are before the word `nice`.

I've also added word boudaries arround the words to match.

Finally the code is:

```
$match_this = '\bcola\b';
$until = '\bnice\b';
$sentence = 'cola this cola is a nice cola';

if(preg_match_all("/$match_this(?=.*$until)/", $sentence, $matches)){
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
```